# How can I make camera axis use "perspective mode by default?

Tags: 3d-view

When I use the keys "1, 3, 7" etc I get the frontal lateral view etc. And if I use "5" key the camera changes to perspective view. Is there a way to make the axis use perspective view by default instead orthographic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go to Edit > Preferences > Navigation > Auto : Perspective and turn it off.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thank you!